# Why is express-sessions creating a connect.sid cookie even though I have resave and saveUninitialized set to false?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, express-session

I'm still a beginner when it comes to using express and sessions, so I'm confused as to why a session cookie is being generated even though I am not logged in through passport.js?

I have resave and saveUninitialized both set to false...

```
// Passport config
app.use(session({
    secret: 'thaeth16h1a6th1ae6',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());
```